# How to handle exception when passing driver into page object in cucumber step file

Tags: java, cucumber, appium

I've created a Java/Appium/Cucumber project using the page object model.

I have a BaseCapabilities class which creates a driver for me:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class BaseCapabilities {

    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException{

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    File filepath = new File("src");
    File fs = new File(filepath,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus_5_API_25");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>
            (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

    return driver;
    }
}
```

I have some page object classes:

```
public class LandingPageElements {

    public LandingPageElements(AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "text(\"Media\")")
    private AndroidElement media;

    public void clickOnMediaButton() {
    media.click();
    }
}
```

If I create a simple unit test with Junit, the tests run fine:

public class TestSteps {

```
@Test
public void firstTest() throws Throwable{
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    LandingPageElements l1 = new LandingPageElements(driver);
    MediaElements m1 = new MediaElements(driver);
    AudioFxElements a1 = new AudioFxElements(driver);

    l1.clickOnMediaButton();
    m1.clickOnAudioFxButton();
    a1.check60HzIsDisplayed();
}
```

}

However I'm at a complete loss as to how I will implement these in my "Steps" glue code for Cucumber. For example, if I have a given/when/then, I'm not able to initialise my page objects as I need to pass my driver, however when I do it throws an "unhandled exception" error. There is no way for me to handle this exception as it means I have to contain it within a method then it won't be accessible to each given/when/then step. The "**capabilities()**" method call below is saying there is an unhandled exception. How do I handle this, but still allow my steps to access the initialised objects?

public class Steps extends BaseCapabilities{

```
LandingPageElements l1 = new LandingPageElements(capabilities());
MediaElements m1 = new MediaElements(capabilities());
AudioFxElements a1 = new AudioFxElements(capabilities());


@Given("^I click on Media$")
public void i_click_on_media()throws Throwable{
    l1.clickOnMediaButton();
}

@When("^I click AudioFx$")
public void i_click_audiofx(){
    m1.clickOnAudioFxButton();
}

@Then("^I can see the 60 hz option$")
public void i_can_see_the_60hz_option() throws Throwable{
    Assert.assertTrue(a1.check60HzIsDisplayed());
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Use dependency injection to help in creating objects and managing object state across steps. Try out picocontainer which is practically invisible other than requiring constructors to inject object. -- http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer and https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/picocontainer. Do not extend BaseCapabilities class in Steps, will not work with multiple Step classes. Inject the driver class into the constructor of the Step class, same for pageobjects. Let the DI container do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the driver in the step class. When the step class grows and becomes large or start working with multiple domains, use dependency injection as suggested in the comment.

I wrote the [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) refereed to in the comment.

I would not start there tho, I would start with a simpler solution with one step definition class that is self contained and can handle all its needs.

This is in the spirit, "make it work, make it understandable, make it fast" where making it fast often is optional.